# C++ memory leak auto detection library

Tags: c++, memory

I am searching for memory leak detection library. 
Something like I would just include it into source code then it should start detecting. External programs might be good but i was looking for some library which can be linked into executable. 

This i am searching for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this was for very long time the best tool:
 http://www.paulnettle.com/pub/FluidStudios/MemoryManagers/Fluid_Studios_Memory_Manager.zip
Just include 1 header file and you're done with it :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use some techniques in your code to detect memory leak. The most common and most easy way to detect is, define a macro say, DEBUG_NEW and use it, along with predefined macros like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to locate the memory leak in your code. These predefined macros tell you the file and line number of memory leaks.

DEBUG_NEW is just a MACRO which is usually defined as:

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
```

So that wherever you use `new`, it also can keep track of the file and line number which could be used to locate memory leak in your program.

And `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` are [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which evaluate to the filename and line number respectively where you use them!

Read the following article which explains the technique of using DEBUG_NEW with other interesting macros, very beautifully:

[A Cross-Platform Memory Leak Detector](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm)

---

From [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_new),

> Debug_new refers to a technique in C++
>   to overload and/or redefine operator
>   new and operator delete in order to
>   intercept the memory allocation and
>   deallocation calls, and thus debug a
>   program for memory usage. **It often
>   involves defining a macro named
>   DEBUG_NEW, and makes new become
>   something like new(_*FILE*_, _*LINE*_)
>   to record the file/line information on
>   allocation.** Microsoft Visual C++ uses
>   this technique in its Microsoft
>   Foundation Classes. There are some
>   ways to extend this method to avoid
>   using macro redefinition while still
>   able to display the file/line
>   information on some platforms. There
>   are many inherent limitations to this
>   method. It applies only to C++, and
>   cannot catch memory leaks by C
>   functions like malloc. However, it can
>   be very simple to use and also very
>   fast, when compared to some more
>   complete memory debugger solutions.

Comment: +1 from me. This is one of my favorite ways to detect leaks but maintaining a list of allocated addresses and checking them against address being sent for deletion on every delete is performance incentive(O(n)=nlog(n)).It is important to mention here, to use the technique only in debug builds and not on release builds.

Comment: @Als: I thought it was obvious that this technique should be used in debug build only, as the macro name I chose (or usually chosen) is `DEBUG_NEW`.

Comment: Just a explicit mention of the same. You have my +1 anyways :) I couldn't see any unicorn just as other day though....

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/), it is much easier to use than the Visual Studio built-in one.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio has such feature on Windows. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=VS.90).aspx . Under linux I do not know if such things exist, but [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is really good to find all kind of memory problems (not only leaks, but also invalid reads for instance).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VC++, that functionality is built in. See [Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) for non-MFC apps and [Detecting memory leaks in MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx52ww7.aspx#BKMK_Memory_leak_detection_in_MFC) for MFC apps.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the above, I can advise a few good programs :^) As example? it would be good to use deleaker for Windows.