# Overriding memory allocation method standard libraries use?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

Is it possible to override the way STL allocates, manages, and frees memory?  How would one do so, if it's possible?  Is there a way to do this in a way that keeps the code that handles the raw memory in one class or file?

I would like to do this for my entire program so I can keep track of memory usage, timing, and lifetime info.  Purely out of curiousity of course!

Comment: Yes... It's pretty difficult... and Yes... Can you achieve the same thing by using `valgrind`?

Comment: If you're on linux, you can take a look at man (2) brk and sbrk. No idea on windows though.

Comment: You have to replace operators `new` and `delete` for that, so run -not walk- to the bookstore and get Chapter 8 of [Effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by redefining the operators `new` and `delete` in one of your files.

The linker will override the standard ones by yours when resolving symbols.

You'll find lots and lots of answers on SO, like this one: [overloading new/delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583003/overloading-new-delete) or that one: [How to track memory allocations in C++ (especially new/delete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438515/how-to-track-memory-allocations-in-c-especially-new-delete) .

There exist some libraries on the internet that do that for you as well, like [Memtrack](http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html) or [this one](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm) . SO has also some resources on that: [C++ memory leak auto detection library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530750/c-memory-leak-auto-detection-library) .

Comment: thought the question addresses the allocator parameter in STL templates

Answer (score 2):

Standard Library classes that manage data with dynamic storage duration take an [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) as one of their template arguments. The class will then make calls to an instance of the allocator for memory management. For instance you can do `std::vector<int, MyAllocator> somevec;` or `std::list<Node*, MyAllocator> someList;` to provide custom allocators to containers.

Here is an [SO Q&A about allocators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529302/845568). The answer the link goes to includes skeleton code for an allocator that should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Aw yeah, that's right, I forgot allocators were a template argument.  I vaguely remember them being described as complicated affairs to code, but I'll give that a swing

Comment: Actually a basic allocator is quite easy to make. Take a look at the requirements outlined in the link included in my answer. Also here is some skeleton code to create standard library compatible allocator - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12529302/845568 - it should be a decent start for you.